# Is there a gi.repository documentation for python?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk3

I'm looking for a `gi.repository` module documentation and I can't find anything on the internet.
All I found is documentation of new Gtk3 libraries for C, or old [PyGtk 2.0 Reference Manual](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/)

I'm looking for something like [PyGtk 2.0 Reference Manual](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/) but for Gtk3.

Is there something similar for Python? (I'm not looking for `dir(Gtk)` or `help(Gtk)` in the Python console.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you're looking for [this](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

It's a work in progress, but basically is a tutorial for Gtk3 in python. I doesn't really cover any other thing aside from Gtk widgets (so no Glib, for example), but it's still useful to get started.

Comment: That's a tutorial, helpful (sortof) but its not an API reference.

Answer (score 33):

Yes, I found a site that contains documentations for all python bindings of perhaps all GNOME projects that are supported by the python gi.repository module or the Python GObject Introspection module:
http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/

The one specifically for GTK is:http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/index.html

There is also documentation specific to the `gi` package provided by PyGObject:
https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/api/api.html

I hope you find these links helpful

Comment: Thanks! :) Link is working and the documentation is perfect! And IMHO this should be the accepted answer, as this is not a tutorial but a complete API reference.

Comment: Unfortunately libide is completely missing. Otherwise: great API documentation! For everyone searching an API documentation for writing gnome-builder extensions. Have a look in the c header files located at /usr/include/gnome-builder/libide/ (or similar, given that you have builder installed). Alternatively have a look In the source: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-builder/tree/src/libide
This really helped me a lot as the tutorial linked on the official site is anything but verbose.

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking, you should be able to use the C library documentation as your main reference. The naming conversions between the C functions and their Python versions are quite consistent, so it's straight-forward in most cases. I would not expect to see Python-specific Gtk-via-introspection documentation.

I occasionally had trouble finding, for example, constants at first. In this case, using iPython's tab-completion to search the Gtk, Gdk and Gobject namespaces was invaluable. There are a few rare cases in which introspection is impossible and, at least in the last version I was working with, they hadn't been manually implemented (can't remember exactly which functions), so there's not much you can do with those; I had to dig into the gi.repository source to verify these cases.

Answer (score 4):

Currently the gi-documentation for python is in development. It will appear in gtk3.4 or later.

You can currently either [build it on your own](https://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection/Doctools), or use unofficial generated versions like [here](http://people.gnome.org/~johnp/girdocsalpha/Gtk/). But be careful, they can contain information from future versions.

Answer (score 2):

Give a look at the GNOME Wiki, most of the useful information on Gobject Introspection is there:

- http://wiki.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection
- http://wiki.gnome.org/PyGObject/IntrospectionPorting