# Right to Left in Python GTK+ 3

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk3

Is there a way to change direction of `Gtk.Window` in sample code below and make it Right to Left? i tried to change it with gravity but didn't worked.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="DEMO")
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_gravity(Gdk.Gravity.NORTH_EAST)

        grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(grid)

        button1 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 1")
        button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 2")
        button3 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 3")
        button4 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 4")
        button5 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 5")
        button6 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 6")

        grid.add(button1)
        grid.attach(button2, 1, 0, 2, 1)
        grid.attach_next_to(button3, button1, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1, 2)
        grid.attach_next_to(button4, button3, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 2, 1)
        grid.attach(button5, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        grid.attach_next_to(button6, button5, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1)

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: You are trying to do what?

Comment: in Left to Right window when you add a widget (like button) to window, button will placed in top left corner (top left corner(0, 0)) will be refrence point. i want to start from right top corner. i hope i explaned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="DEMO")
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_gravity(Gdk.Gravity.NORTH_EAST)
        self.set_direction(Gtk.TextDirection.RTL)
        grid = Gtk.Grid()
        grid.set_halign(Gtk.Align.END)
        grid.set_direction(Gtk.TextDirection.RTL)
        self.add(grid)
        button1 = Gtk.Label(label="Button 1")
        button1.set_halign(Gtk.Align.START)
        button1.set_direction(Gtk.TextDirection.RTL)
        button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 2")
        button3 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 3")
        button4 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 4")
        button5 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 5")
        button6 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 6")

        grid.add(button1)
        grid.attach(button2, 1, 0, 2, 1)
        grid.attach_next_to(button3, button1, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1, 2)
        grid.attach_next_to(button4, button3, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 2, 1)
        grid.attach(button5, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        grid.attach_next_to(button6, button5, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1)

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

By the way, you can easily figure stuff like this out by using Glade to create a mockup.

**Edit**: according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978848/how-can-i-show-text-with-different-language-direction-in-gtk), you would change the direction. It didn't work for me, but maybe my language settings have something to do with it.

See also [set_direction](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-direction).

Comment: grid.set_halign(Gtk.Align.END) doesn't make any difference. it is hard to believe that GTK dosn't have any feature for right to left layout. for people how has right to left language like arabic or persian

Comment: you know, in right to left layout every thing start form right side of window even Window Title. and right side of window would be start point (0, 0)

Comment: thanks for helping me but python gave me this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SimpleWindow.py", line 51, in <module>
    win = MainWindow()
  File "SimpleWindow.py", line 18, in __init__
    gtk_widget_set_direction(grid, GTK_TEXT_DIR_RTL)
NameError: name 'gtk_widget_set_direction' is not defined

Comment: Although what you suggested works perfectly in GTK+ C, but not PyGObject

Comment: I guess you realize `gtk_widget_set_direction(grid, GTK_TEXT_DIR_RTL)` is C. Python is `grid.set_direction(Gtk.TextDirection.RTL)`. Why this wouldn't work in Python but works in C baffles me. Could you post your C code for me to try out? I have almost zero experience in C.

Comment: `grid.set_direction(Gtk.TextDirection.RTL)` Works. i think i used c code for python [sad face]. could you tell me where did you found this? because when i search for gtk reference or pygobject reference all i get was c GTK. Thankyou for helping me.

Comment: There is no really good Python reference for Gtk. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420108/is-there-a-gi-repository-documentation-for-python). I just learned how to port the C to Python.